# Sharepoint Column Totals to User - Value defined by status

Tags: web-services, javascript, jquery, calculated-column

So I have two list databases.

User Points
User Submissions

These two databases work together. A user 'submits' for points in a status of 'submitted'/UserPoints[PendingPoints:Column] once 'approved' UserSubmission[TotalPoints:Column] points are now 'TotalPoints'

I have a work flow that does this math for me. If 'approved' 
CurrentUser[UserPoints]PendingPoints - CurrentItem[Points] then Add CurrentItem[Points]+TotalPoints then update list item.
^^^ This works but has this flaw...

If a user types a wrong point value it will double add...
Or is the data is deleted it doesn't delete the item(s) points...

I am wanting to do a script I guess that would calculate a TOTAL colum defined by user.

Total database is 30 users.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PreSaveAction to add your script.

Add an HTML Form Web Part and then add your logic to the function.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function PreSaveAction(){
//Do some stuff
}
</script>
```

I personally like to use JQuery to get and set values within my SharePoint pages. Here is some info on one method of [how to add JQuery to SharePoint](http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/193). You can also use this function to verify the inputs on the form.

Comment: Does not accomplish what I wanted... Still working on it and it is a little more complex than the above script. I as well am using jQuery...

Any other ideas?